Number of triangles in a convex polygon——about Catalan Number

How many ways are there to divide a convex polygon with $n$ sides into
$n-2$ triangles at disjoint diagonals?

Obviously, the problem make sense only if $n \geq 2$.
And the answer can be formulated by the formula below:

$$ f(n)=\begin{cases}   \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}f(k)\cdot f(n-k+1),n≥4 \\  
1,n=2,3 \end{cases} $$

My question is: why does the $f(n)$ equal to $C_{n-2}$ which is the $(n-2)$-th Catalan number?
As I know, $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_k\cdot C_{n-k-1}$. Letting $n=n-2$, we get: $C_{n-2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}C_k\cdot C_{n-k-3}$, which is not equal to the $f(n)$.

Doesn't the problem make sense only for $n \ge 3$, not $n \ge 2$?

@Amogh Sure,it does. But maybe extending to n≥2 helps to serve calculation purpose.

Hint: Find a bijection between up-down paths that don't go under the x-axis, and polygon triangulations (that don't intersect). $\quad$ If you're stuck, there are lots of write-ups online, like the related links on the right.

After a few days, I finally figured out the crux of the issue. It turned out to be a careless mistake of formula transformation..
For
$f(n)=\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}f(k)\cdot f(n-k+1)$
letting $k=k-2$:

$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}f(k+2)\cdot f(n-k-1)$

letting $n=n+2$:

$f(n+2)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k+2)\cdot f(n+2-k-1)$

letting $f(n)=C_{n-2}$, we get $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_k\cdot C_{n-k-1}$, which is exactly the recurrence formula of Catalan number.
So $f(n)=C_{n-2}$ sets up.
